# Identify last record in MailMerge

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

When working with a list of items (using RangeStart and RangeEnd), how to you identify the last record?

The examples I've seen so far use `IF` and `MERGESEQ` to check for the first item or use `SET` to set a value to be checked later.

If I want to write some text when on the very last item, what will it look like?

`{ IF { MERGESEQ } = "?" "Sign here" "" }`